# Non-capturing subpattern still matching (PHP regex)

Tags: php

So I'm trying to use a non-capturing subpattern but it's not working. Below is an example code of what I'm trying to do.

```
preg_match("/(?<=Title:)(?:.*?)(\d+-?)+/i", "Title: [123-232dfafewf323]", $match);
```

So basically, I need a look behind regex to look for the title/header thing, then I don't really care what's in between the actual pattern and the look behind. However, what this returns is no different than having no non-capturing subpattern, i.e. ( [123-232)

Comment: So what you want from the example is just the 232? Seems to work fine here https://regex101.com/r/jV3kI6/1

Comment: No, I need it to get '123-232'

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using subgroups.

`preg_match("/(?<=Title:).*?((\d+-?)+)/i", "Title: [123-232dfafewf323]", $match);`